# Begünstigter oder Begünstiger?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

If **Begünstigter** means "beneficiary, a person who receives money", then what does **Begünstiger** mean?

There are no entries for either in Duden...

Comment: Scheint eine Großkatze zu sein ;)

Answer (score 6):

The "Begünstiger" would be the other side of the transaction, so to speak. The "Begünstigter" receives some kind of benefit (often money, but not always) from the "Begünstiger". If you want to pair it with the English terminology, the "Begünstigter" would be the "beneficiary", while the "Begünstiger" would be the "benefactor".

The term "Begünstigter" isn't really used in everyday language. It's mostly found in legal texts like insurance contracts. This holds true even more for "Begünstiger". In a quick search I only found one example, [§ 257](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__257.html) of the Strafgesetzbuch (the German penal code):

> (1) Wer einem anderen, der eine rechtswidrige Tat begangen hat, in der Absicht Hilfe leistet, ihm die Vorteile der Tat zu sichern, wird mit Freiheitsstrafe bis zu fünf Jahren oder mit Geldstrafe bestraft.
> (...)
> (4) Die Begünstigung wird nur auf Antrag, mit Ermächtigung oder auf Strafverlangen verfolgt, wenn der Begünstiger als Täter oder Teilnehmer der Vortat nur auf Antrag, mit Ermächtigung oder auf Strafverlangen verfolgt werden könnte. § 248a gilt sinngemäß.

I won't go into the legal details (which would clearly be outside my expertise anyway), but the idea of the two paragraphs is as follows: If somebody committed an illegal act, and a second person aides the first person with the intent that the first person can keep the spoils of their illegal deed, then the second person can be punished as well - for "Begünstigung".

Under German law, some offenses can only be prosecuted if a specific person (often the victim) files a formal request to do so (a so called "Antragsdelikt"). The latter of the quoted paragraphs says that prosecution of the offense of "Begünstigung" needs to clear the same hurdles that would be in place for the original crime. So, if the original crime is an"Antragsdelikt", the "Begünstigung" of this crime is an "Antragsdelikt" as well. In this context, the person doing the "Begünstigung" is called the "Begünstiger".

As you see, the term does exist, but it's only used in very specific cases. In addition to what I explained above you may run into it in the context of an inheritance or an endowment, but that's probably about it.

Comment: So if I were to credit money to some company's bank account, I would be "der Begünstiger" and the company would be "der Begünstigter", right?

Comment: @KeNSmilePachI Technically yes, but I'm not sure those specific terms are used in banking jargon. As I tried to illustrate in my answer, both terms, but especially "Begünstiger", have a very narrow usage spectrum.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Assume that X favors Y, in German *X begünstigt Y*. Then

- X = (der) Begünstiger, (die) Begünstigerin
- Y = Begünstigter, der/ die Begünstigte

### More elaborate answer

There are a couple of verbs that are used to express that one person, X, does something to another person, Y. In other words, X performs the action and Y receives the action. Some examples are

- küssen (X küsst Y)
- schlagen (X schlägt Y)
- anklagen (X klagt Y an)
- begünstigen (X begünstigt Y)

From these you can derive nouns that refer to one or the other person.

#### Referring to X

There are two ways to refer to the person who does the action, X. One way is to append to the **stem** of the verb the suffix *-er* or *-erin*, respectively, depending on the gender:

- *küss-* → (der) Küsser, (die) Küsserin
- *schlag-* → (der) Schläger, (die) Schlägerin
- *anklag-* → (der) Ankläger, (die) Anklägerin
- *begünstig-* → (der) Begüstiger, (die) Begünstigerin

(Notice also the umlauts.)

Another way to refer to X is appending to the **Partizip Präsens** form of the verb the suffix *-e* or *-er*, respectively, depending on the gender and whether or not there is a definite article:

- *küssend* → der/ die Küssende, Küssender, Küssende
- *schlagend* → der/ die Schlagende, Schlagender, Schlagende
- *anklagend* → der/ die Anklagende, Anklagender, Anklagende
- *begünstigend* → der/ die Begünstigende, Begünstigender, Begünstigende

#### Referring to Y

If you want to refer to the person who receives the action, Y, you append to the **Partizip Perfekt** form of the verb the suffix *-e* or *-er*, respectively, depending on the gender and whether or not there is a definite article:

- *geküsst* → der/ die Geküsste, Geküsster, Geküste
- *geschlagen* → der/ die Geschlagene, Geschalegner, Geschlagene
- *angeklagt* → der/ die Angeklagte, Angeklagter, Angeklagte
- *begünstigt* → der/ die Begünstigte, Begünstigter, Begünstigte

#### A remark regarding usage

Notice that some forms are more and others less common in certain contexts. For example: *Er ist ein guter Küsser* versus *Der Küssende schloss die Augen*. Or in court you will hear *Ankläger* more often than *Anklagender*. In contrast, *der/ die Begünstigende* sounds more natural to me than *der Begünstiger* or *die Begünstigerin*, but I wouldn't be much surprised to find the latter in legal texts.